JS - VSCode no consol.log output in Terminal
I have an issue with loggin output to my terminal:

I run node version 23.4.0

Using Node and writing JS in my CLI on windows works perfectly fine

In Vs Code, I have created the file app.js

app.js is saved in the starters folder

app.js contains the following code:


console.log("starting app");
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.status(200).send('Hello From the Server Side')
});

//App.listen allows to start a server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port} ...`)
});


In the Terminal, there is no output (see screenshot)
enter image description here

The "Output" tab in the console is blank

Un-install and re-install node.js

Try to log sth. with a new file calles test.js that contains one line of code: "console.log("Hello World". Was not successful



The white dot in the file tab tells me you didn't save the file.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

what's going on with your node executable? why is it intermittently not found?
